# Criar uma única função change para vários seletores CSS em Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Uso a função abaixo para adicionar classes CSS (blue, red, pink...) numa DIV ".container" a partir de uma select "#selcolor". É possível eu usar essa mesma função em outras tags select com IDs diferentes? Nesse caso as classes (blue, red, pink...) não seriam adicionadas na DIV ".container", ou seja, a variável "div_action" da função teria que ser modificada.

```
  function select_changed() {
    jQuery('select#selcolor').each(function() {
      var selected = jQuery(this).val();
      var div_action = '.container';
      if(selected == '') {
        jQuery(div_action).addClass('');
      } 
      if(selected == 'blue') {
        jQuery(div_action).addClass('blue');
      } else {
        jQuery(div_action).removeClass('blue');
      }
      if(selected == 'pink') {
        jQuery(div_action).addClass('pink');
      } else {
        jQuery(div_action).removeClass('pink');
      };
      if(selected == 'red') {
        jQuery(div_action).addClass('red');
      } else {
        jQuery(div_action).removeClass('red');
      };
    });
  }
  $('select#selcolor').change(function() {
    select_changed();
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer.

Uma opção é usar um parâmetro na função `select_changed` para definir qual é o elemento alvo:

```js
function select_changed(target){
    jQuery('select#selcolor').each(function() {
      var selected = jQuery(this).val();
      if(selected == '') {
        jQuery(target).addClass('');
      } 
      if(selected == 'blue') {
        jQuery(target).addClass('blue');
      } else {
        jQuery(target).removeClass('blue');
      }
      if(selected == 'pink') {
        jQuery(target).addClass('pink');
      } else {
        jQuery(target).removeClass('pink');
      };
      if(selected == 'red') {
        jQuery(target).addClass('red');
      } else {
        jQuery(target).removeClass('red');
      };
    });
}

$('select#selcolor').change(function() {
  select_changed('.container');
});

$('select#selcolor').change(function() {
  select_changed('.outro-container');
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Então, mas a segunda tag select no html vai ter uma ID diferente. Por exemplo, a select#selcolor adiciona as classes na div ".container", enquanto uma outra select, essa chamada de #selcolor2 adiciona as classes numa outra div.

Comment: Então edite sua pergunta pra incluir esses detalhes.

Comment: Não entendi, era isso mesmo? Só aceita a resposta se estiver correta @Rafael